# Rx Extensions - Proper way to use delay to avoid unnecessary observables from executing?

Tags: coffeescript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm trying to use delay and amb to execute a sequence of the same task separated by time.
All I want is for a download attempt to execute some time in the future only if the same task failed before in the past. Here's how I have things set up, but unlike what I'd expect, all three downloads seem to execute without delay.

```
    Observable.amb([
        Observable.catch(redditPageStream, Observable.empty()).delay(0 * 1000),
        Observable.catch(redditPageStream, Observable.empty()).delay(30 * 1000),
        Observable.catch(redditPageStream, Observable.empty()).delay(90 * 1000),
        # Observable.throw(new Error('Failed to retrieve reddit page content')).delay(10000)
        # Observable.create(
            # (observer) ->
                # throw new Error('Failed to retrieve reddit page content')
        # )

    ]).defaultIfEmpty(Observable.throw(new Error('Failed to retrieve reddit page content')))
```

full code can be found here. [src](https://github.com/bendavisnc/RedWall_Coffee/blob/master/RedWall.coffee)

I was hoping that the first successful observable would cancel out the ones still in delay.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delay` doesn't actually stop the execution of what ever you are doing it just delays when the events are propagated. If you want to delay execution you would need to do something like:

`redditPageStream.delaySubscription(1000)`

Since your source is producing immediately the above will delay the actual subscription to the underlying stream to effectively delay when it begins producing.

I would suggest though that you use one of the `retry` operators to handle your `retry` logic though rather than rolling your own through the `amb` operator.

```
redditPageStream.delaySubscription(1000).retry(3);
```

will give you a constant retry delay however if you want to implement the linear backoff approach you can use the `retryWhen()` operator instead which will let you apply whatever logic you want to the backoff.

```
redditPageStream.retryWhen(errors => {
  return errors
          //Only take 3 errors
          .take(3)
          //Use timer to implement a linear back off and flatten it
          .flatMap((e, i) => Rx.Observable.timer(i * 30 * 1000));
});
```

Essentially `retryWhen` will create an Observable of errors, each event that makes it through is treated as a retry attempt. If you error or complete the stream then it will stop retrying.